# How to make Flask Heroku app a Progressive Web Application (pwa)

Tags: flask, heroku, progressive-web-apps

I've deployed a simple web application named "ogagnage" with Flask and Heroku (gunicorn). It works perfectly in production and I try now to run it as a Progressive Web Application. Following Heroku instructions, I've created manifest.json and service workerfile (sw.js). Manifest file is recognized by my browsers but not service worker and i unfortunately don't understand why...
[Manifest.json OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkqFT.jpg)

[sw not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5osOn.jpg)
[sw error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmsVd.jpg)

Here is the structure of my project:
[Directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQou6.jpg)

And here are the code added:

**In views.py :**

```
@app.route('/sw.js')
def sw():
    return app.send_static_file('sw.js')

@app.route('/manifest.json')
def manifest():
    return app.send_static_file('manifest.json')

@app.route('/app/static/app.js')
def app_js():
    return app.send_static_file('app.js')
```

**In sw.js :**

```
console.log('Hello from sw.js');

importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.2.0/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log("Yay! Workbox is loaded ");

  workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
    {
      "url": "/",
      "revision": "1"
    }
  ]);

  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:js|css)$/,
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
      cacheName: 'static-resources',
    }),
  );

  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'images',
      plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
          maxEntries: 60,
          maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );

  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('https://fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com/(.*)'),
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'googleapis',
      plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
          maxEntries: 30,
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );
} else {
  console.log("Boo! Workbox didn't load ");
}
```

**In app.js:**

```
    (function() {
      if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
                   .then(function(registration) {
                   console.log('Service Worker Registered');
                   return registration;
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('Unable to register service worker.', err);
          });
          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
            console.log('Service Worker Ready');
          });
        });
      }
    })();
```

**In my base template:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
```

**And my git:**
[Github project](https://github.com/tivui/ogagnage)

Hope someone could help me, it would be a beautiful Christmas present.
Tx

Answer (score 2):

You also need to send the manifest.json file

```
@app.route('/manifest.json')
def manifest():
    return app.send_from_directory('static', 'manifest.json')
```

If you'd like a complete example, I have created a Flask PWA before. Here is the repository: https://github.com/MurphyAdam/Flask-chatbot

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer and for sharing your git. I've updated with @approute of manifest.json In my browser (Firefox), it's OK for manifest configuration. But Service Worker still not recognized. (cf error message capture in updated post). My structure is similar to yours in your chatbot app , the contents of the files too. Something escapes me...

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem after changing @app routes in views.py and relative path to go to sw.js in app.js (cf code updated)
Now , my service worker is working:
[Service Worker Ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iifvt.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the correct code in your answer as well?